# How do I extend a named Spring bean when using a @Qualifier specified bean injection point?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, autowired

How do I extend a named bean when using a `@Qualifier` specified bean injection point?

I have project 1 consisting of 3 [spring](/questions/tagged/spring) beans:

```
@Component("bean1")
public class Bean1 implements Bean {
}

@Component("bean2")
public class Bean2 implements Bean {
}

@Component("bean3")
public class Bean3 {
    private Bean bean;

    public void setBean(@Qualifier("bean1") final Bean bean) {
        this.bean = bean;
    }
}
```

This project is bundled into a jar and included as a dependency on my 2nd project:

```
@Component("bean1")
@Primary
public class Bean1Child extends Bean1 {
}
```

What I want to happen is for the bean, `Bean1Child`, to be injected into `Bean3`'s setter method. Unfortunatly I am receiving an error.

> org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException:
>   Annotation-specified bean name 'bean1' for bean class [Bean1Child]
>   conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name
>   and class [Bean1]

I needed to use `@Qualifier` so that `Bean2` is not injected into `Bean3`  Using the `@Primary` annotation did not help. How can I have `Bean1Child` injected into `Bean3` when running from my 2nd project?

Comment: The easiest workaround is to exclude `Bean1` from scanning in the project 2. Is it a Spring Boot application. If not, do you have Java or XML config?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is possible, you can change the way the beans are created by removing the `@Component` annotations:

In the first project, the `BeanChild3` would be refactored to get the `bean` in the constructor

```java
public class Bean3 {
    private final Bean bean;

    public Bean3(final Bean bean) {
        this.bean = bean;
    }
}
```

Then we can create the beans in a `BeansConfig` class

```java
@Configuration
class BeansConfig {

   @ConditionalOnMissingBean
   @Bean("bean1")
   Bean bean1(){
      return new Bean1();
   }

   @Bean("bean2")
   Bean bean2(){
      return new Bean2();
   }

   @Bean("bean3")
   Bean bean3(@Autowired @Qualifier("bean1") Bean){
      return new Bean3(bean);
   }

}
```

The `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` allows us to provide another bean with the same name to be used instead. If no such bean exists, then the default one would be used.

You will then need to create a `beanChild1` bean in your second project and it should be picked up.

```java
   @Bean("bean1")
   Bean bean1(){
      return new Bean1Child();
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve this using `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` feature.

Modify your `Bean1` class as below

```
@Component("bean1")
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(type = "bean1")
public class Bean1 implements Bean {
}
```

modify `Bean1Child` class as below

```
@Component
@Qualifier("bean1")
@Primary
public class Bean1Child extends Bean1 {
}
```

**How it works?**

- Spring will try to load a bean named "bean1". If it doesn't find any bean by the same name that is marked as `@Primary` it will fall back to `Bean1` class and load it as "bean1".
- `Bean1Child` has to be marked as primary because spring is going to find 2 beans by the same name. We need to tell which to load.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple beans of the same type and want to prevent `Bean2` from injecting. In some project inject `Bean1` and in others `Bean1Child`.

There are multiple options.

### Override bean definition with `@Bean`

Make `Bean1Child` bean definition the same as `Bean1` has using `@Bean`

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

  @Primary
  @Bean
  public Bean1 bean1() { //return type must be Bean1
    return new Bean1Child();
  }
}
```

and set the property `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true`

### Create custom `@Qualifier` annotation

```
@Qualifier
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface BeanType {

}

@BeanType
public @interface Bean1Type {
}

@Bean1Type
@Component("bean1")
public class Bean1 implements Bean {
}

@Component("bean2")
public class Bean2 implements Bean {
}

@Component("bean3")
public class Bean3 {

  private final Bean bean;

  public Bean3(@Bean1Type Bean bean) {
    this.bean = bean;
  }
}

@Bean1Type
@Primary
@Component("bean1Child")
public class Bean1Child extends Bean1 {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot have two beans specified with the same qualified name, as the error indicates:

```
Annotation-specified bean name 'bean1' for bean class [Bean1Child] 
conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [Bean1]
```

Giving a different qualifier name to Bean1Child should work.

```java
@Component("bean1child")
@Primary
public class Bean1Child extends Bean1 {
}
```

and in Bean3 , `public void setBean(@Qualifier("bean1child") final Bean bean) {`

Comment: I cannot change the qualifier because I need project 1 to inject Bean1 when it is run without the 2nd project